# C# parameters in interface

Tags: c#, interface

```
class Test {
    public Test(string name, string age) {
    }
}

interface ITest
        ????????

class Example: ITest {
    public Example(/* ... */) {
    }
}
```

So what should I use in my interface to use the same parameters in my example as in test?

What I want to do:

- I have 3 classes: `a`, `b` and `c`.
- I want my `c` to inherit from both `a` and `b`.

But C# doesn't let you do that ... So I want to use an interface.

**EDIT**
My classes are:

- Student(name, age, studies)
- Teacher(name, age, classes)
- Working Student/Teacher(name, age, studied/classes, payment)

So i want to use methods in my working class from the other classes.

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are used as a contract for classes that inherit it. This means any public methods/properties you want the interface to expose, must also be exposed in the inherited class.

In the case above, you don't have any public methods/properties exposed in the interface. Let me show you an example.

```
Interface ITest
{
   void AddPerson(string name, string age);
}

Interface IPerson
{
    string ReturnPersonsAge(string name);
}

/// This must expose the AddPerson method
/// This must also expose the ReturnPersonByAge method
class Example : ITest, IPerson
{
   Dictionary<string, string> people = new Dictionary<string, string>();

   void AddPerson(string name, string age)
   {
      people.Add(name, age);
   }

   string ReturnPersonsAge(string name)
   {
      return people[name];
   }
}
```

I hope that helps, but feel free to ask more questions so I can help narrow down your question.

Comment: hey, What i want to do:

I have 3 classes -> a, b and c I want my C to inherit from both a and b. But c# doesn't let you do that... So i want to use a interface.

Comment: i thought you can't inherence from more then 1 class ??

Comment: Sorry Multiple Inheritence is not allowed, but you are allowed to inherit from multiple INTERFACES, which is slightly different. See edit.

Comment: Yea i knew that i had to use interfaces =D Ty for your answer nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can't define constructors. There certainly is other way to do it, depends on what you want to achive.

Answer (score 0):

```
Interface IAClass
{
  void Add(string s);
}
Interface IBClass
{
  void Delete(string m);
}


Class A: IAClass
{
  void Add(string name)
{
  // Your Logic
}
}

Class B: IBClass
{
  void Delete(string name)
{
  // Your Logic
}
}

Class C:IAClass,IBClass
{
     void Add(string name)
{
  // Your Logic
}

 void Delete(string name)
{
  // Your Logic
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can expose them as properties in the interface

```
Interface ITest
{
string Name{get;set;}
string Age{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: And if i use Public Test(params string[] parameters)